# Why is Hikari's nickname "Pikari"?

Tags: japanese-language, amanchu

In Episode 1 of *Amanchu!*, Hikari states that her nickname is Pikari. In the English subtitles, she offers this explanation

[image]
[image]

> **Hikari**: Due to my overly peppy nature, people in junior high called me "Peppy Hikari", "Peppykari", and finally just "Pikari".

Where does this name come from in the original Japanese?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the word for lightning strike "pikkari".

Comment: take the p from peppy and ikari from hikari and you get pikari maybe

Comment: @Dragon That was the explanation in English. I'm looking for the explanation in the original Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japanese, Pikari (ぴかり) is one of the numerous mimetic words of the language, meaning "in a flash"/"sparklingly"/"brilliantly", mostly associated with thunder and lightning. (Also, Hikari itself means "light", but I don't really know if it's related or not.)

Given the energetic and cheerful nature of Hikari, it's a fitting nickname.

Some references :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_sound_symbolism
- http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%B4%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A

Comment: Also, Hikari in Hiragana is written as ひかり while Pikari is ぴかり. The only difference is that Pikari uses the small o (forgot what it is called) on the top right corner of the hi (ひ) character.

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same letter with a diacritic (it's called a _handakuten_ if I'm not mistaken) to indicate that the H becomes a P.

Comment: I figured that Hikari meaning "light" was a reference to _Aria_; Akari also means "light", and Hikari and Akari look similar and play similar roles in the story.